# OOP based GUI with wxPython

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

Firstly, thanks to all.  Over the past few months I have referred to all the help and guidance that can be found on these boards, which has helped me to “grasp” python a bit better!

I’m still learning so... easy words please!

Now, down to the issue!

I would like to develop a fairly ‘OOP heavy” GUI in the sense that objects will be created, inheriting from classes that inherit from classes ( via composition NOT from multiple inheritance ;) )

I have now hit a roadblock - it may be clearer if I outline my steps:

1. Create a ‘main frame’
2. Add a splitter window to this frame
3. Add a treectrl to the left hand side of the splitter

Now, this is where the issues start...

I would like to create an object (with its own panel, which contains a notebook with various information pertaining to the instance of the object.

Each instance of this object, when selected from its corresponding tree item from treectrl, should then fill up the right side of the splitter, with a different instance notebook every time.

This is the issue!

I have tried show/hide the object.panel reference and also tried to use the splitterwindow replace window function- to no avail.

Some of the things I have tried did kind of replace the right panel, but also showed the original panels widgets...?

If anyone could help, it would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Add some code to illustrate your intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the tree control's selection events. I would bind to those and when they get fired, you would update the right side of the display. You can usually do this by either resetting the widgets on the right with new data, or by hiding / destroying those widgets and placing new ones in their place.

I have an XML editor that you can look at that might help you see how this sort of thing could be done:

- https://github.com/driscollis/boomslang

Unfortunately there is a lot of code that would be needed to fully demonstrate the concept that you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice.

As I was reading your reply regarding the treectrl events - I thought I would quickly try to ReplaceWindow(oldpanel, newpanel), followed by hiding the old and then showing the new.

This done the trick! What the wxPython documentation failed to state is that hiding and then showing the respective old and new panels after the replacewindow method is called, is necessary to correctly effect the change. This may be because the parents of both old and new panels is the splitterwindow?

Anyhow, the following code may help someone else out who might stumble across this issue / post and show the concept of what I was trying to achieve.

Thanks for your help!

Alex

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):

def __init__(self):



    wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False, filename='test')

    self.f1 = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title='APP', pos = (100, 100), size=(1000, 700))
    self.split = wx.SplitterWindow(self.f1)     

    self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(parent=self.split)
    self.oldPanel = wx.Panel(parent=self.split)
    self.newPanel = wx.Panel(parent=self.split)     

    self.oldLabel = wx.StaticText(parent=self.oldPanel, label='This is the old panel...', pos=(50, 50))
    self.newLabel = wx.StaticText(parent=self.newPanel, label='This is now the new panel!', pos=(50, 50))




    self.oldBut = wx.Button(parent = self.leftPanel,label='Show Old Panel', pos=(50, 50))
    self.newBut = wx.Button(parent = self.leftPanel, label='Show New Panel', pos=(50, 75))


    self.leftPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.showOld, self.oldBut)               
    self.leftPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.showNew, self.newBut)


    self.split.SplitVertically(self.leftPanel, self.oldPanel)
    self.split.SetMinimumPaneSize(100)
    self.split.SetSashPosition(300)

    self.f1.Show()
    self.SetTopWindow(self.f1)


def showOld(self, event):
    self.split.ReplaceWindow(self.split.GetWindow2(), self.oldPanel)
    self.newPanel.Hide()
    self.oldPanel.Show()


def showNew(self, event):
    self.split.ReplaceWindow(self.split.GetWindow2(), self.newPanel)    
    self.oldPanel.Hide()
    self.newPanel.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```